# cucumber + webrat: checking text appearing twice

Tags: rspec, cucumber, webrat

I am working on a rails app to self teach BDD and testing in general. Using cucumber + webrat + rspec, after railcasts video tuts. 
In this app a quiz has_many questions. The view I am testing should render the question twice and non contiguously. (not testing contiguity here)
I have a cucumber scenario aimed at checking this

```
Given quiz titled "Pearl Jam" has questions named "Corduroy, Dissident"
When I go to the experiment page for quiz titled "Pearl Jam"
Then I should see "Corduroy" twice
And I should see "Dissident" twice
```

My step is defined like this:

```
Then /^I should see "([^\"]*)" twice$/ do |text|
  regexp = Regexp.new(text + "(.+)" + text)
  response.should contain(regexp)
end
```

I tested the regex with a tool, and it seems to work, but the test fails on cucumber.
I googled for some documentation, but webrat's only documentation is the API docs; I wasn't able to get the response displayed as text.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried response.**body**

```
Then /^I should see "([^\"]*)" twice$/ do |text|
  regexp = Regexp.new(text + "(.+)" + text)
  response.body.should contain(regexp)
end
```

Comment: It's easy to miss these things when you get caught up in the code!

Answer (score 1):

I had to modify Damian's answer to get this to work across lines.

```
Then /^I should see "([^\"]*)" twice$/ do |text|
  regexp = Regexp.new(text + "(.+)" + text, Regexp::MULTILINE)
  response.body.should contain(regexp)
end
```